# Menu Strip and Status Strip conceals the form elements

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a menu strip and status strip whose `Dock` property is set to `Top` and `Bottom` respectively. I need to display a table (i.e. `TableLayoutPanel` object) programmatically which covers the full form so I have set its `Dock` property to `Fill`. The problem is that the status strip and the menu strip covers the top and bottom parts of the `TableLayoutPanel` object, concealing it. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Make 3 rows in the table layout panel

Comment: Tends to happen when you add the Menu/StatusStrip *after* you added the TLP.  Docking order is determined by the control order, something you can only easily see with the View > Other Windows > Document Outline window.  The simple workaround is to right-click the TLP and select "Bring to Front".

Comment: After creating `TableLayoutPanel` call `tableLayoutPanel.BringToFront()` method if you do it in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `Panel` to your form via the designer. Stretch it out so it covers the area where you want your `TableLayoutPanel` object, then set the Anchor property of your new Panel to `Top, Bottom, Left, Right`.

Then just do `panel1.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel1);`

Answer (score 1):

For this problem there is a table layout panel (which you were already using, so you were almost there).

Instead of docking your controls to top or bottom you make a row for the control in the table layout panel and just fully dock it.

Example of table layout panel with 3 rows and controls docked: 
[image]

As you can see they don't overlap and the tablelayout panel takes care of sizing (you can set % per row, or fixed px etc.)

So what you essentially need is a table layout panel to hold your table layout panel